# zurb-foundation 5 came out yesterday - is there an updated gem file?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Trying to update the ruby zurb-foundation gem today. I thought foundation also got an updated gem after releasing version 5. Is there an updated version or is version 4.3.2 the latest gem in the repository?

I tryed:

```
gem search --remote --al zurb-foundation
```

result was:

```
zurb-foundation (4.3.2, 4.3.1, 4.3.0, 4.2.3, 4.2.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.
4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.0.9, 4.0.8, 4.0.7, 4.0.5, 4.0.4, 4.0.3, 4.0.2, 4.0.1
.5, 3.2.4, 3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.2.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.9, 3.0.8, 3.0.7, 3
 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 2.2.1.2, 2.2.1.1, 2.2.1.0, 2.2.0.2, 2.2.0.1, 2.1.5.1,
1.4.3, 2.1.4.2, 2.1.4.1, 2.1.4, 2.1.3.1, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.0, 2.0.3.
2.0.3.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.0.0, 0.0.5)
ZURB-foundation (2.2.1.4, 2.2.1.3, 2.2.1.2, 2.2.1.1, 2.2.1, 2.2.0.1,
2, 2.1.5.1, 2.1.5, 2.1.4.1, 2.1.4, 2.1.3.3, 2.1.3.2, 2.1.3.1, 2.1.3)
```

Answer (score 3):

They've released the gem under a different name, it's just called `foundation` now instead of `foundation-zurb`.

Installation instructions can be found at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html.

Comment: The `foundation` gem only contains a CLI for Foundation. The gem you most likely need is `foundation-rails`. (https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails)

Comment: @DanielRikowski The installation instructions from ZURB do not include `foundation-rails`. Personal note: I did manage to get a project using the instructions on that page, however it didn't work the first day (I got a public key error) but one or two days later, it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, thats true, my comment is misleading. I just saw the words "gem" and "foundation" and as a Rails guy I automatically assumed this was a Rails-specific question. I wanted to point out that the Rails specific stuff is not available in the `foundation` gem, but in `foundation-rails`.

Comment: They updated the upgrade instructions to include `foundation-rails`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thing. It looks like they use bower now. I find its rather annoying to have to install nodejs, git and bower just to get the latest release.

Edit:
More here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html